# Doctrine indexBy annotation by a entity field

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine, one-to-many

I have the next structure that define travel destinations in different languages.

[image: EER]

In `Destinations`, the method that retrieve Collection of `DestinationsTranslate` *(getDestinationsTranslations)* I need index by `id` field of `Language` entity to be able to call, for example `$destinationEntity->getDestinationsTranslations()->get('en')` to retrieve the translation of destination in english; but if I set `idLanguage` in `indexBy` annotation, does not work. I try:

- indexBy="idLanguage"
- indexBy="idLanguage.id"
- Set __toString to Languages entity.

Nothing of this works. If I try to index by `translation` field, works.

Is it not possible to index by an entity?

The entity of `Destination` is:

```
/**
 * Destinations
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="destinations", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_destinations_time_zones1_idx", columns={"id_time_zone"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Destinations
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=3, nullable=false, options={"fixed"=true,"comment"="Three letter IATA code."})
     * @ORM\Id     
     */
    private string $id;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mac", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"comment"="Indicate if it is a metropolitan airline destination."})
     */
    private $mac = false;

    /**
     * @var \TimeZones
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TimeZones")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_time_zone", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private TimeZones $idTimeZone;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DestinationsTranslation::class, mappedBy="idDestination", indexBy="idLanguage.id")
     */
    private $destinationsTranslations;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(string $iata, TimeZones $tz, bool $mac = false)
    {
        $this->id           = $iata;
        $this->idTimeZone   = $tz;
        $this->mac          = $mac;
        $this->destinationsTranslations = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

The entity of `Languages` is:

```
/**
 * Languages
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="languages", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Languages
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=2, nullable=false, options={"fixed"=true,"comment"="Two letter code from ISO 639-1."})
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private string $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64, nullable=false, options={"comment"="ISO 639-1 language name."})
     */
    private string $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DestinationsTranslation::class, mappedBy="idLanguage")
     */
    private $destinationsTranslations;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(string $code, string $name)
    {
        $this->id   = $code;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->destinationsTranslations = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

The entity of `DestinationsTranslation` is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DestinationsTranslationRepository::class)
 */
class DestinationsTranslation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Languages::class, inversedBy="destinationsTranslations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private Languages $idLanguage;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Destinations::class, inversedBy="destinationsTranslations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private Destinations $idDestination;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private string $translation;

    public function __construct(Languages $lang, Destinations $dest, string $translation)
    {
        $this->idLanguage       = $lang;
        $this->idDestination    = $dest;
        $this->translation      = $translation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way of naming the relationships, I re-generated the entities with the relationship fields without setting `id` in their name, the doctrine command generated it automatically and can perform the indexBy.

The annotation was like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DestinationsTranslation::class, mappedBy="destination", indexBy="language_id")
 */
 private Collection $destinationsTranslations;
```